# Чтения файла размером 55GB

Tags: java, файлы, выделение-памяти

Есть файл 50GB +

Необходимо прочесть его построчно и сложить все значение в HashSet для получения количества уникальных строк.

Как это можно реализовать ? Стандартные методы падают с outOfMemory.

Comment: А сколько там у вас уникальных строк? Код добавьте, пожалуйста. И фрагмент файла не помешал бы

Comment: "Все стандартные варианты" - ??

Comment: *Нужно прочесть его построчно, и сложить все значения в HashSet! В итоге нужно получить количество (уникальных) строк.* Из цели никак не проистекает выбранный способ её достижения. Почему именно так? да ещё с такой категоричностью?

Comment: По количеству строк скажу, что их миллионы, а то и больше. Код простейший, построчное считывание через BufferedReader, и через стримы пробовал и сканером. Но проблема то я так понимаю, в HashSet? Как туда передать такое количество  значений.

Comment: Если уникальных строк больше чем количество доступной памяти, то никак вы это без OutOfMemory не сделаете

Comment: (можно попробовать считать количество по более компактным хэш-суммам, но у них бывают коллизии)

Comment: Может, стоит зайти с другой стороны. Зачем вам HashSet этих уникальных строчек?

Comment: B итоге просто нужно количество уникальных строк, через set думал проще сделать, они ведь там по умолчанию уникальны

Comment: А хотя в принципе можно зайти с другой стороны и предварительно разделить файл на несколько частей по какому-то критерию, например по первому байту строки или её хэш-суммы - получится до 256 маленьких файлов, в каждом файле можно посчитать количество отдельно и потом результаты подсчёта объединить. Но это прокатит только если HashSet на самом деле нафиг не нужен

Comment: @andreymal да, вариант "хранить данные во время вычисления не в оперативной, а в постоянной" неплох

Comment: все верно, такой объем мы в оперативной памяти то не вытянем, а как тогда  данный в постоянную перенести?

Comment: прочитайте гигабайт, сохраните результат. и так до конца файла. потом возьмите все результаты и с ними работайте. сливайте по два потом и т.п.

Comment: Может подойти более глобально. Как должны будут использоваться полученные данные. Нужен список уникальных строк и сколько эта строка встречается в файле или просто количество уникальных строк?

Comment: @Z.John "B итоге просто нужно количество уникальных строк" (c) автор вопроса.

Comment: Можно попробовать хранить список индексов уникальных строк, где строка в первый раз встречается, конечно ее придется перечитывать, но это не будет занимать много памяти. Конечно там можно попробовать накрутить еще какой-нибудь  кэш   где хранить ни все уникальные строки, а только последние - ну это уже наворот. Пока можно попробовать просто перечитывать по индексу строк.

Comment: Вам поможет NIO и его каналы чтения и записи